# Trigger form submit on button click in Vue Unit Test

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

Is there a way to actually trigger the submission of a form by clicking on a submit button in a Vue Unit Test?

Let's take this simple component:

```html
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="$emit('submitEventTriggered')">
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

You can find a similar component as an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6qcfe49x).

I want to test that `submit.prevent` gets triggered when the button is clicked and therefore the `submitEventTriggered` is emitted. When I run this in a browser everything works as expected, but the following test fails:

```js
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import {assert} from 'chai'
import Form from '@/components/Form.vue'

describe.only('Form', () => {

    it('button click triggers submit event', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Form)

        wrapper.find('[type=\'submit\']').trigger('click')

        assert.exists(wrapper.emitted('submitEventTriggered'), 'Form submit not triggered')
    })
})
```

With this output:

```
AssertionError: Form submit not triggered: expected undefined to exist
```

If I change the action to trigger `submit.prevent` on the form directly everything works fine, but then there is actually no test coverage for the submitting via button.

```
wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit.prevent')
```

It seems like the `trigger` function doesn't actually click the button.

Why is this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: This seems to me like a bug. I reported it here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1030

Comment: Would like to know why/who downvoted you

Comment: Having the same issue - commented on the github issue - hopefully it can be resolved.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Note:** The previous method used `attachToDocument`, [which has been deprecated](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument),

---

The issue is that Vue Test Utils does not attach DOM nodes to the document by default. This is to avoid enforcing cleanup. You can solve this by setting `attachTo` to an HTML element when you mount the component:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.id = 'root'
document.body.appendChild(div)

it('button click triggers submit event', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Form, {
    attachTo: '#root'
  })

  wrapper.find("[type='submit']").trigger('click')

  assert.exists(
    wrapper.emitted('submitEventTriggered'),
    'Form submit not triggered'
  )
})
```

You should remove the DOM node from the document to avoid a memory leak. You can do this by calling `destroy` on the wrapper:

```js
wrapper.destroy()
```

Comment: Where is the documentation of `Vue Test Utils does not attach DOM nodes to the document by default`?

Comment: @DanielListyoEmanuel https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument

Comment: this isn't working for me, and the [`attachTo` example on the Vue Test Utils site doesn't either](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachto), is there some config that needs to be added for `attachTo` to work with `mount`/`shallowMount`?

Comment: the example in the vue test utils website has an error (a PR was submitted to fix it so it might be corrected soon)
`expect(wrapper.vm.$el.parentNode).to.not.be.null` 
should be
`expect(wrapper.vm.$el.parentNode).not.toBeNull()`

Comment: I got the error `Error: Not implemented: HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit`.
So instead of triggering the submit via the button, I did like below:
`wrapper.findComponent('form').trigger('submit')` and I could remove the `attachTo` and others. May be useful in case one does not need to test DOM features, but only the submit event of the form

Comment: @MarcoArruda's comment helped me, but I used `wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit')` not `findComponent()`.